# after 1 second automatically type text within span using keyup trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

after clicking on a button I am reading text within span tag and printing into the input box.
here what I want to achieve is on clicking on the button I want to print the first character which is 'H' and after 1 sec pass, I want to print 'e'  and so on till string finish. I want to use keyup and trigger jquery functionality within it.

till now what I tried is. any help really appreciated.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>trigger demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div><span class="hello">Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world </span></div>
trigger above text here: <input type="text" name="fname" id="input1">
<button class="world">trigger</button>
<br>
<script>
$( ".world" ).click(function() {
setInterval(function(){
var hello = $( ".hello" ).text();
console.log(hello);
var a = $('#input1').trigger('keyup');
console.log(a); }, 1000);

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of using keyup here .?

Comment: i want to type whole string dynamically that's why I am using keyup

Comment: then why using button click .?

Comment: after button click, i will start the interval which is 1 sec and after each 1 sec i want to print each character within string

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I don't think that you need `keyup` event. What you want is setting a delay and showing a single char one by one until reach the text's last char.

So split the whole text into an array and setTimeout for each char. To achieve this, I use an [IIFE(immediately-invoked function expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to create a closure.

For further reading about IIFE:
[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

```js
$(".world").click(function() {
  var text = $(".hello").text().split("");
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var value = $('#input1').val()
      $('#input1').val(value + text[i])
    }, 1000 * (i+1));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span class="hello">Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world </span></div>
trigger above text here: <input type="text" name="fname" id="input1">
<button class="world">trigger</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t actually need the keyUp event to accomplish what you are trying to do. You can simply use the length of the current input value, compared against the total length of the original text to help determine, and output the next character every second until the two match. Similar to the following example

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>trigger demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
  <div><span class="hello">Hjust a test </span></div>
  trigger above text here: <input type="text" name="fname" id="input1">
  <button class="world">trigger</button>
  <br>  
</body>
</html>
```

The JQuery/JavaScript

```
var setIntervalId = null;

function printNextChar(inputText){
    var currentInputLenth = $("#input1").val().length;

  if (currentInputLenth == inputText.length){
    stopInterval();
  } else{
    updateInput(inputText);
  }  
}

function updateInput(inputText){
    var input1 = $("#input1");

  var currentInputLength = input1.val().length;
  var currentInputValue = input1.val();
  var nextChar = inputText[currentInputLength];

  input1.val(currentInputValue + nextChar);
}

function stopInterval(){
    clearInterval(setIntervalId);
}

$(".world").click(function(){
  var startText = $( ".hello" ).text();

  setIntervalId = setInterval(printNextChar, 1000, startText);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9vmptndo/

Let me know if that helps, thanks

Comment: Excellent! Can you upvote the answers please if they were useful to you, thanks